# Andamento do paradigma orientado à aspecto

Tags: orientação-a-aspectos, aop

Hoje pouco se fala em POA, porque ele não é mais comentado nas redes? O que causou o seu "desaparecimento", se não está obsoleto, onde está sendo aplicado.

O projero [Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) do spring.io usa fortemente o AspectJ. Mas também nunca ví pessoas utilizando o Roo.

Vale a pena estudar esse paradigma(ainda)?

Comment: Hoje também pouco se fala sobre [a roda](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roda), mas isso não quer dizer que a tecnologia seja irrelevante. Aqui mesmo no SOPT, a tag [tag:orientação-a-objetos] é uma das que aparecem [na primeira página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags), devido à quantidade relativa de perguntas sobre o assunto.

Comment: Realmente, é algo passível de opinião, mas pra mim parece concreto que estudar esse paradigma vai lhe ser útil por no mínimo dois aspectos: (1) vai te permitir trabalhar *bem* com a grande maioria das linguagens modernas e *mais facilmente* com as demais e (2) vai facilitar que você aprenda os outros tantos paradigmas existentes, entre eles o [SOA (Arquitetura Orientada a Serviços)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) e o [AOA (Arquitetura Orientada a Agentes)](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-paradigma-orientado-a-agentes/28791).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consigo saber se realmente é menos falado, não conheço pesquisa específica quanto a isto. No entanto, AOP não desapareceu e se fala bastante sim, basta ver a quantidade de questões apenas na tag [aop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aop) no SOen, pesquisando por [aop](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aop) também no SOen.

Se seu interesse maior é em projetos do Spring, você pode começar por [aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

No Spring como um todo AOP é muito utilizado. Quando você usa Spring MVC, Data, Social, gestão de transações, etc. cada parte dele está usando AOP de alguma forma, mesmo que você não perceba tão claramente. Por exemplo, apenas alterando em uma classe das quais o(s) objeto(s) são gerenciados pelo contexto do Spring de `@Component` para `@Service` (e vice-versa) terá diferenças

No Java EE AOP está também bastante presente, observe por exemplo os [`interceptors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkeed.html), isto apenas falando do uso em tecnologias java, [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#Implementations) poderá ver mais uma lista de suporte em algumas plataformas, seja nativo ou não.

Quanto se vale a pena estudar, depende, AOP é um paradigma que coexiste com outros, você pode um dia precisar, pode não, então não dá para falar se ainda compensa ou não, depende de contexto.

Em muitos casos bastante útil; em outros, bastante obscuro. Basta usar projetos do Spring e se pegará pensando *onde está este log*, pois em grande parte é feito *logging* com uso de aspectos, o que pode tornar difícil seguir fluxos de execução em determinados casos.

Comment: Então o oap seria um paradigma que dá suporte a outros paradigmas?

Comment: @AndréHenriques meio que isso, ele se integra muito bem com outros paradigmas, devido ao fato de agir a "eventos". Eu não conheço uma linguagem que é AOP, algo como algumas são OOP, então não consigo ser certo quanto a isto. Irei pesquisar a fundo isto e atualizo a resposta.